# How do I create a row in R with each row element equal to the number of values in its column?

Tags: r, count, rbind

I was thinking of maybe using two of the following concepts:
1. rbind
2. some sort of thing like COUNT in SQL

Imagine table X:

```
[A · B  · C ]
[1 · 2  · 3 ]
[3 · NA · 4 ]
[6 · NA · NA]
```

With the addition of a new row, my new table X(1) would look like:

```
[A · B  · C ]
[1 · 2  · 3 ]
[3 · NA · 4 ]
[6 · NA · NA]
[3 · 1  · 2 ]
```

With the [3 · 1 · 2] signifying the number of elements above itself.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. You might was to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Can you provide some example data and an example of what you would like as the output?

Comment: Hey Sarah! Of course. Say for example I had a datatable with columns A: [1, 2, 3, 4] and B: [1, 2, NA, 5] and C: [3, 4, NA, NA]. I would want to add another row at the bottom that would count the number of elements in each column. So now, each column would be A: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]. B: [1, 2, NA, 5, 3]. C: [3, 4, NA, NA, 2]. The new bottom row would be [4, 3, 2] because column A has 4 elements, B has 3, and C has only 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of rbind and rowSums of non-NA values. See below.

Also for future reference if you provide data in a more easily reproducible format it is more helpful. For example how I have below or  for more complicated data you can run `dput(X)` and post the output that is returned

```r
X <- data.frame(A = c(1,3,6), B = c(2,NA,NA), C = c(3,4,NA))

rbind(X, rowSums(!is.na(X)))
#>   A  B  C
#> 1 1  2  3
#> 2 3 NA  4
#> 3 6 NA NA
#> 4 3  2  1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>